# specify interpretation scope to interpret decimal string as Nat

Tags: idris

Is there a way to tell Idris to interpret decimal strings such as `2`, `10`, etc as `Nat`? The default behavior in the repl is to interpret them as `Integer`. In Coq, for example, it's possible to specify an interpretation scope with `%` to disambiguate notations, so I guess I'm hoping that something like `10%Nat` exists. Is there something like that in Idris?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard prelude contains

```
the : (a : Type) -> (value: a) -> a
the _ = id
```

which can be used to give explicit types:

```
the Integer 10
the Nat 6
the (Vect 3 Int) [1,2,3]
```

There's also `with [namespace] [expr]`, which privileges `namespace` inside `expr`. This seems closer to `%`, but `the` seems more often used.

```
with Vect [['a', 'b']] -- Vect 1 (Vect 2 Char)
with List [['a', 'b']] -- List (List Char)
```

You can make a syntax extension for `the`:

```
syntax [expr] "%" [type] = the type expr
5%Nat
10%Int
```

But not for `with`.